# What is the difference between revise and reformulate?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between revise and reformulate? For example in the sentence, "the scientist revised/reformulated his hypothesis"?

**Revise**: reconsider and alter (something) in the light of further evidence

**Reformulate**: formulate again or differently

**Formulate**: create or prepare methodically:

Does revise have more of a suggestion of improvement?

Comment: What did you find when you compared the definitions?

Comment: Please show the overlaps and any differences you have found in say Collins, AHDEL and RHK Webster's Dictionaries.

Comment: People don't generally do things over again unless there is a reason, and that reason usually is to improve, for whatever reason, something that had been done before. Whether one revises, reformulates, reorganizes, retools, or whatever, it is always out of the hope to make things better this time.

Comment: "Revise" simply means "change".  "Reformulate" implies significant structural changes (the "methodical" construction needed to be redone).

Answer (score 2):

In programming, as well as in writing (to some extent):

**revise**: finding bugs/errors and fixing them

**reformulate**: put in another form/shape, recreate parts of the program/manuscript

The second is generally deeper, **more concerned with the style**.

The first is **more concerned with the grammar**, but not necessarily.

However, the demarcation is tricky, as the first can involve segments with the 2nd.